# Invoke AWS Lambda across regions using step functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

ers,

I have a Step Function pipeline which links several Lambda's. The Step Function is started using a AWS API Gateway. All aforementioned items are in the same region.
However, based on the clients IP origin, I would like to use one lambda of the step function in a different region. I did some research but it seems there is no way of invoking a lambda in a different region as compared to the step function region.

So basically this would mean that I would have to make different API Gateway entrypoints and different Step Function pipelines, different Lambdas for every region I would like to employ to right? Are there some consequences for the S3 storage I use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Step Functions don't support cross-region Lambda's (and it appears they don't) my idea would be to use a 'proxy-lambda' in the same region as the Step Function and within the proxy-lambda invoke the cross-region lambda. It's not ideal, you will have to handle pass-through and you will pay twice for the duration of the lambda (1x proxy 1x actual lambda) but it seems a lot easier than having all the elements in all regions.

Comment: I like the idea, this saves me a lot of time getting all of the other components in place. But how would I invoke this other lambda from the proxy lambda? I am doing my development in Java.

Comment: You can use the AWS SDK for Java to invoke the Lambda. If needed you can even do this cross-account using a resource policy, but within the same account that would not be needed.

Comment: I think your comment is the way forward, however I am running into some problems which I describe here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53782781/aws-invoke-lambda-within-lambda-across-regions

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm too late to this, but proposing my idea anyway.
Maybe use SQS? Put an event into an SQS in the other region and add a lambda trigger.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To make this answer more effective, add some code and maybe some documentation links